# Strange certificate in keychain

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

I've found a strange certificate in osx keychain.

I don't remember installing it and it is marked as "it was signed by an unknown authority".

It was installed in my login keychain and it "seems" to be related to Akamai, but it doesn't seems to be correctly signed at least...

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to have it installed by error? As it wasn't set to "always trust", can have it been used by applications without showing an error? Is there anyway to see its installation date?

Comment: If you do not trust the CA, you should remove the cert.

Comment: I've marked it not to trust it never...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, there appears to be a legitimate internal Akamai CA by this name — i can't know if yours is real, or a fraudulent impersonation — used by employees to sign emails. See, for example:

- https://marc.info/?l=openssl-users&m=144440523209028&w=2
- https://marc.info/?l=pgsql-performance&m=135543233530391
- https://marc.info/?l=rtir&m=140932980701502&w=2

(If the CA is only intended for internal use and not publicly trusted, the employees probably only used it on public emails by mistake.)

I don't know if this happens, but it wouldn't surprise me if you received a signed email from some mailing list, and your email client automatically saved the CA.

Such a CA also shows up in Censys, though this doesn't really answer any questions:

- https://www.censys.io/certificates/5021ede7b1a9028d0402567257e9696c826738a1e7c1ac7931731a094cfd979d
- https://www.censys.io/certificates/4b41f652e93f67341251dbf53c6b21c7e3ca11b8541a69ec6130ab8138fdc285
- https://www.censys.io/certificates/cd3467a4e4840df96fde16d11c1a018acdb61bb91bae369478f12dfe008c09c6

Comment: Thanks for your answer! At least I can think of a legit use and not an attack. Is there anyway to check if this certificate is really from akamai?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that some software that you might have gotten from the torrents or another pirated source installed that certificate onto your computer. It is not impossible since you would be providing your root password during installations.

Yes, it is possible that you installed it unknowingly. But no, without having "always trust" set, it would ask you for authorisation every time, or so it should!

I doubt it is possible to figure out when the cert was installed.

Comment: Thanks!

I've been searching in google and it seems to appear in several p7s files...

Comment: @zapico, Ah, I see. Though p7s is an Outlook related format as far as I know.